# How would one remove a directory with a .htaccess rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

everyone!

I have multiple employees on my site with their individual projects. I have an issue though, as the website is set up like this:

```
site.com/myownproject1

site.com/myownproject2

site.com/john/projectbyjohn1

site.com/john/projectbyjohn2

site.com/james/projectbyjames1

site.com/james/projectbyjames2
```

I would like to set up my .htaccess file to rewrite to those folders when someone tries to access the directory without the name prefix, so

```
site.com/john/projectbyjohn2
```

would be accessible through

```
site.com/projectbyjohn2
```

This is what my .htaccess currenlty looks like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
#Lots of stuff that does not matter
```

**EDIT:** Full .htaccess as of now:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [S=2]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mitch/$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mitch/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mitch/$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 400 /ErrorDocument.php?err=400
ErrorDocument 401 /ErrorDocument.php?err=401
ErrorDocument 402 /ErrorDocument.php?err=402
ErrorDocument 403 /ErrorDocument.php?err=403
ErrorDocument 404 /ErrorDocument.php?err=404
ErrorDocument 405 /ErrorDocument.php?err=405
ErrorDocument 406 /ErrorDocument.php?err=406
ErrorDocument 407 /ErrorDocument.php?err=407
ErrorDocument 408 /ErrorDocument.php?err=408
ErrorDocument 409 /ErrorDocument.php?err=409
ErrorDocument 410 /ErrorDocument.php?err=410
ErrorDocument 411 /ErrorDocument.php?err=411
ErrorDocument 412 /ErrorDocument.php?err=412
ErrorDocument 413 /ErrorDocument.php?err=413
ErrorDocument 414 /ErrorDocument.php?err=414
ErrorDocument 415 /ErrorDocument.php?err=415
ErrorDocument 416 /ErrorDocument.php?err=416
ErrorDocument 417 /ErrorDocument.php?err=417
ErrorDocument 500 /ErrorDocument.php?err=500
ErrorDocument 501 /ErrorDocument.php?err=501
ErrorDocument 502 /ErrorDocument.php?err=502
ErrorDocument 503 /ErrorDocument.php?err=503
ErrorDocument 504 /ErrorDocument.php?err=504
ErrorDocument 505 /ErrorDocument.php?err=505
```

Comment: Do you know ahead of time what "projectbyjohn1", "projectbyjames2", etc. will be?

Comment: Yes, I know what they will be called, and I am willing to manually specify them in the .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [S=2]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/john/$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/john/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /john/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/james/$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/james/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /james/$1 [L]
```

The first rule skips the following two if the directory/file already exists in the root. The next two simply resolve a file/directory based on where it's found, inside `/john` or `/james`.

Please note that if both John and James decide to name a file or sub-directory the same, then we're in a pickle. The rule defined first, in our case `/john`, will supersede in such cases.

Comment: This gives a 404 error on all pages, without showing the defaulted 404 page. Error: /[S=2] not found

Comment: There needs to be a `-` before `[S=2]`. Hence, the error. Could you try again?

Comment: That works for redirecting it - Thank you, but I am interested in rewriting it :/

Comment: The rules above **do not** redirect. Perhaps, one of your other rules might be interfering.

Comment: What exactly happens when you go to `site.com/projectbyjohn2`?

Comment: It goes to site.com/john/projectbyjohn2 - Which is what I want it to do, except I want it to show site.com/projectbyjohn2 in the URL bar

Comment: Could you post any other rules that come after my rules? esp. the ones with `[R]` or `[R=301]` at the end. These are the rules that would cause `R`edirection to happen.

Comment: I have added the current .htaccess as an edit to the original post

Comment: This is unrelated to the core issue here but you'll need `[S=1]` there. The number should equal the number of such rules placed directly below. Since, there's only Mitch right now, `S` should be one.

Comment: Could you also confirm that the sub-directories don't have any `.htaccess` files of their own? They could interfere as well. The only rule that could possibly redirect in your main htaccess file is the `https` one. I'm assuming you're already accessing your urls with https, right?

Comment: Already accessing with SSL active, yes. I will change the [S=2], I was not aware. The subdirectories do not have an .htaccess